# LinkedIn v1 to v2 API migration

Tags: android, linkedin-api, access-token

As per LinkedIn announcement, we need to migrate to version 2.0 of our APIs and OAuth 2.0 so as per release document I have change my `GET`request url from

```
 https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,email-address,skills,educations,positions,location,phone-numbers)?requestToken?scope=rw_nus+r_fullprofile&format=json&oauth2_access_token=
```

to

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me/~:(first-name,last-name,email-address,skills,educations,positions,location,phone-numbers)?requestToken?scope=rw_nus+r_fullprofile&format=json&oauth2_access_token=
```

And I'm getting the below response:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Resource me does not exist",
    "status": 404
}
```

Please help me out, what is wrong from my side? What changes need to be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's more to simply changing the `v1` to `v2` and `people` to `me` in the URL.

To request [specific fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/lite-profile), you pass in `?projection=` instead of `~:` for example:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName)
```

Also keep in mind that fields have changed in v2. By default, you will only have access to [lite profile fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/lite-profile), unless you're part of [LinkedIn Marketing Partners](https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners) program.

Comment: Hey @Ervin as per your suggestion I made these changes now I'm getting `{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET /me","status":403}`  this error please help me

Comment: And the user has given your app access to at least r_liteprofile?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Try removing the app from user's settings and reauthorize the app. It's working just fine for me https://prnt.sc/msz1se

Comment: Just tried the same thing still getting the same error :(

Comment: What's your GET request? The one in the question is wrong.

Comment: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName)?requestToken?scope=r_liteprofile&format=json&oauth2_access_token=` this is my `GET` request

Comment: If the authenticated user has already given you permission to r_liteprofile, there's not need to pass requestToken and scope in the request. Format param is also not allowed. I also see multiple ? which is wrong. Only the first query param has ?, the rest should have &. This should be your call. Replace token with your access token. 

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName)&oauth2_access_token=TOKEN

Comment: Thanks @Ervin for your help. I have accepted your answer.